# How to know with jQuery that a "select" input value has been changed?

Tags: javascript, html, events, jquery

I know that there is the `change` event handling in `jQuery` associated with an input of type `select`. But I want to know if the user has selected another value in the select element ! So I don't want to run code when the user select a new element in the select but I want to know if the user has selected a different value !
In fact there are two select elements in my form and I want to launch an ajax only when the two select elements has been changed. So how to know that the two elements has been changed ?

Comment: Question is not very clear , can you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specifically listen for a change event on your chosen element by setting up a binding in your Javascript file.

That only solves half your problem though.  You want to know when a different element has been selected.

You could do this by creating a tracking variable that updates every time the event is fired.

To start with, give your tracking variable a value that'll never appear in the dropdown.

```
// Hugely contrived!  Don't ship to production!
var trackSelect = "I am extremely unlikely to be present";
```

Then, you'll need to set up a function to handle the change event.

Something as simple as:-

```
var checkChange = function() {
  // If current value different from last tracked value
  if ( trackSelect != $('#yourDD').val() )
  {
     // Do work associated with an actual change!
  }

  // Record current value in tracking variable
  trackSelect = $('#yourDD').val();
}
```

Finally, you'll need to wire the event up in document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#yourDD').bind('change', function (e) { checkChange() });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you may use `select` event handler (to set values for some flags). This is how it works:

```
$('#select').change(function () {
  alert($(this).val());
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dXmsD/

Or you may store the original value somewhere and then check it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var val = $('#select').val();    
  ...
  // in some event handler
  if ($('#select').val() != val) ...
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the value on page load in some hidden field.

like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 $('hiddenFieldId').val($('selectBoxId').val());
then on change you can grab the value of select:
});
    $('selectBoxId').change(function(){
    var valChng = $(this).val();
    // now match the value with hidden field
    if(valChng == $('hiddenFieldId').val()){ 
    }
    });
```

Comment: Our project is divided into "actions", "models", "pages" and "views" like a MVC framework. So ....

Comment: MVC is now a common design pattern,jQuery code should be in view and in that view again you can have a hidden field.So its quite a feasible solution I believe.

Comment: But our view is just a call of an object which will call methods representing the page. It's difficult to explain :) In the actions are built an array storing names and types of the elements to display !

Comment: Then you can just store the default value in a JS variable.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to store previous value of the selected option, then you should check if new selected value is different than stored value.

Check out the [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/P9B8u/)!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastValue, selectedValue;
    $('#select').change(function() {
        selectedValue = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        if(selectedValue == lastValue) {
            alert('the value is the same');
        }            
        else {
            alert('the value has changed');
            lastValue = selectedValue;
        }
    }); 
});​
```

Comment: Is it realy works? if i am not wrong lastValue and selectedValue will never be same, always else part will be fired. as it happen in your SAMPLE

Comment: Yes, it actually seems working here http://jsfiddle.net/P9B8u/ , you see that the first and last element values of select input are the same there. if last element is chosen while the first one is active, selectedValue and lastValue will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("select").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
          });
      $("div").text(str);
    })
    .change();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change